# Data Dictionary in Oracle indicating pk and fk

Tags: database, oracle

I am new to database, and much more in oracle. Can you help me with a query that generates a data dictionary ?. I need you to list the name of the table, its fields, description, data type, pk, fk, long, null, default.

In the case of the fields `pk`, `fk`, and `null`, indicate with: "no" or "yes".
And in `default` indicate its value (if it has one) by default in case it does not fill data about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation? Search SO? Is this your homework?

Comment: It's something that they ask me in my work, I also have to do it on the sql server. If I have reviewed many examples on the net, some with part of my requirement, I want to make sure it is fine, just that.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has [a data dictionary which is well-documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/toc.htm). You can write your report based on the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view, which provides details for all table columns in your ambit. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2103.htm#REFRN20277).

To identify PK and FK columns you will need ALL_CONSTRAINTS and ALL_CONS_COLUMNS.

The one snag is `description`. That is a business property and not one that Oracle concerns itself with. In a well-controlled database there may be some useful business information in ALL_COL_COMMENTS.

Comment: Thanks for your help, although for some it is easier to subtract points to the question. Well, I'll investigate the points you mention.